# how can i get url after take photo

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

NSURL *assetURL;

if( [picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera )
{
    assetURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]; // always return nil !!
}
else if( [picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary)
{
    assetURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
}
```

how can i get assetURL when i selected UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera.

UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary is work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take an image using `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`, the image is not saved into photo library automatically. You have to write it manually. After writing, you can get the URL.

Sample code:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

        UIImage* cameraImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

        ALAssetsLibrary* assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        [assetsLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:cameraImage.CGImage
                                           metadata:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata]
                                    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

                                        if (!error) {

                                            //use assetURL as you need.
                                        }
                                    }];
    }
}
```

A **warning** though, writing is a time consuming operation.